# vSphere Cluster Management Network

Tags: vmware-esxi, vmware-vsphere

I have a questions regarding where to place the management network for ESXi. I know that it should be separated from other traffic. i have a management network that I have setup already that I use to manage my SAN and other switches can or should I add my management network for the vSphere Cluster to that as well? Anyone have any advice or suggests on this? Thanks

Comment: Yes. Why not? It is your management network, right?

Comment: yeah we just weren't sure because it seems as though vmware has the heartbeat running on their as well

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's three things to consider here, the management traffic, vMotion traffic, and if you're using it, the fault tolerance traffic.

If you're not using FT, then don't worry about that.

Ideally, all these traffic types should be separated into isolated networks. But if it's a small cluster, you can get away with having vMotion and management on the same network, provided that network is otherwise empty. vMotion especially is quite sensitive and should be kept completely separate. The management is usually put into an existing management network. This requires you to set up 2 vmkernel NICs per host, and mark one for vMotion, and put the other in your existing management network. The vMotion can be purely L2, there's no need to have a gateway in it.

vSphere HA, which sends the heartbeats you talked about, uses any available vmkernel NIC it can find, except the ones used for vMotion, so in this setup it'll use your management network.